# How to make BackgroundWorker ProgressChanged events execute in sequence?

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker, race-condition

Consider the following code:

```
private static BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();

static void Main(string[] args) {
  bg.DoWork += bg_DoWork;
  bg.ProgressChanged += bg_ProgressChanged;
  bg.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
  bg.RunWorkerAsync();

  Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

static void bg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
  Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
  Thread.Sleep(100);
  Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
}

static void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bg.ReportProgress(i);
  }
}
```

When run I get the following output:

> 0
>   1
>   1
>   2
>   0
>   3
>   2
>   3
>   5
>   4
>   4
>   6
>   5
>   7
>   7
>   8
>   6
>   9
>   8
>   9

I understand that the issue is a race condition between the threads that BackgroundWorker starts for each call to ReportProgress.

How can I make sure that the whole body of each bg_ProgressChanged gets executed in the order I have called them?
That is I would like to get

> 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9

as a result.

Comment: BackgroundWorker isn't really meant to be used without a UI thread.

Comment: Prefer to use Ist parameter of ReportProgress in the increments and not the userState parameter. Suggest you to please look at this MSDN link for reporting the progress: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx

Comment: Try to wrap the ReportProgress method call in a lock(_objectLock) block e.g. lock(_lockObject) { bg.ReportProgress(i); }

Comment: @Vijay: That won't make any difference at all; those calls run on the same thread.

Comment: @Andris: Why are you using a BackgroundWorker in the first place?

Comment: @SLaks: My original problem was in a Windows Form application. I just created the sample in a Console Application because I did not know that it would make a difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` raises `ProgressChanged` events on the current SynchronizationContext of the thread that called `RunWorkerAsync()`.

The default SynchronizationContext runs callbacks on the ThreadPool without any synchronization.

If you use BackgroundWorker in a UI application (WPF or WinForms), it will use that UI platform's SynchronizationContext, which will execute callbacks in order.

Comment: I have created the sample as a console application with target .NET Framework 3.5. I have changed the output type to Windows application an it worked as you have described.

Comment: My issue is that I would like the whole body of the ProgressChanged event to execute in the order I have called them. I have update the question to reflect better what I would like to do.

Comment: @Andris: Under a UI SynchronizationContext, they will execute in order.

Comment: @SLaks: As I said I have changed the application output type to a Windows application, but please not that in the output in my revised example the first 5 comes before the first 4, so the call with parameter 5 was executed before the one with parameter 4. Isn't changing the output type enough? I'm not sure how to set the SynchronizationContext to a "UI SynchronizationContext".I'm not familiar with the topic.

Comment: You need to run a UI thread by calling `Application.Run()`.  (this is a blocking call).  The project type doesn't matter at all.  However, if you're not doing UI, you probably shouldn't be using a BackgroundWorker at all.

Comment: @SLaks: Thank you. Moving my code into the Load event handler of a form and running `Application.Run()` from Main had the same effect as my answer bellow. So my initial assumption that each `ProgressChanged` event runs on separate threads in a WinForm application was wrong. They all execute on the UI thread and though run neatly one after the other.

Comment: Correct.  This is done by WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Post and the WinForms message loop.

Comment: Why do you think [this tutorial is using `Thread.Sleep()`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners)? Doesn't make any sense to me, when we have ProgressChanged()... however when I implemented solely on BGWorker functions, I realized ProgressChanged() just doesn't seem to fire.

Comment: @bonCodigo: It's using `Thread.Sleep()` to simulate work.  `ProgressChanged` will only fire if you call `ReportProgress()`.

Answer (score -1):

**Do not use this solution!!! May lead to deadlocks as SLaks has pointed it out.**

I seem to have stumbled upon an answer. I changed the code the following way:

```
   [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
   static void bg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
     Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
     Thread.Sleep(100);
     Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
   }
```

and now I get the output I want:

> 0
>   0
>   1
>   1
>   2
>   2
>   3
>   3
>   4
>   4
>   5
>   5
>   6
>   6
>   7
>   7
>   8
>   8
>   9
>   9

Comment: In a UI application, this will make no difference, since the callbacks will only run on the UI thread.

Comment: Note that this can cause deadlocks.  `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` is equivalent to `lock(this)` and should not be used.