# Why BackgroundWorker's Progress event runs on a different thread than it should?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm having problems with `BackgroundWorker`. It seems like it calls its Progress event in a different thread than it was created on, contrary to the documentation. First, for reference:

This is, when worker is being created:

[image: BackgroundWorker created]

This is, when worker is doing its job:

[image: Asynchronous work]

This is, when my code handles progress reported by the worker via `ReportProgress`:

[image: Handling progress]

Note, that the last thread is even different from the previous two (main and BW's worker thread)

The worker is created in App.xaml.cs indirectly:

```cs
public App()
{
    Configuration.Configure(Container.Instance);

    // (...)

    // Configure core service
    coreService = Container.Instance.Resolve<ICoreService>();
    coreService.Init();
}
```

And then:

```cs
public CoreService(ITfsService tfsService, IConfigurationService configurationService, IMapper mapper, IDialogService dialogService)
{
    this.tfsService = tfsService;
    this.configurationService = configurationService;
    this.dialogService = dialogService;
    worker = new CoreWorker(tfsService, configurationService);
    worker.ProgressChanged += HandleCoreWorkerProgress;
}
```

Worker gets executed in `CoreService.Init()`:

```cs
public void Init()
{
    tfsService.Connect();
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Worker itself looks more less like this:

```cs
private class CoreWorker : BackgroundWorker
{
    private const int CORE_WORKER_TIMEOUT = 1000;
    private readonly ITfsService tfsService;
    private readonly IConfigurationService configurationService;

    // (...)

    public CoreWorker(ITfsService tfsService, IConfigurationService configurationService)
    {
        this.tfsService = tfsService;
        this.configurationService = configurationService;

        this.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        this.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }

    protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (this.CancellationPending)
                break;

            if (EnsureTfsServiceUp())
            {
                (var startedBuilds, var succeededBuilds, var failedBuilds) = ProcessBuilds();

                // Download and process builds
                var buildResult = new BuildInfo(startedBuilds, succeededBuilds, failedBuilds);
                ReportProgress(0, buildResult);
            }

            // Wait 1 minute

            Thread.Sleep(CORE_WORKER_TIMEOUT);
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that interally I use async methods, but I wait for them explicitly (since I'm in a separate thread anyway):

```cs
(reachedSince, recentBuilds) = tfsService.GetBuilds(lastBuild.Value).Result;
runningBuilds = tfsService.GetBuilds(runningBuildIds).Result;
plannedBuilds = tfsService.GetBuilds(plannedBuildIds).Result;
```

Is there something I'm missing? Docs says, that progress handling should happen in the same thread as when `BackgroundWorker` was created. But it is not, and I'm obviously getting errors on the UI.

Application is WPF, however it works in background, doesn't have main window, most of its job is done in the CoreService and it displays windows only occasionally.

How can I fix that, so that ReportProgress will run in the main thread?

---

**Update**: I modified my code to use `Task`s instead and used `Progress<T>` to process the progress:

```cs
            notificationTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await ProcessNotifications(new Progress<BaseCoreNotification>(HandleNotificationProgress), notificationTaskCancellationSource), 
                notificationTaskCancellationSource.Token, 
                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
                TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
```

Result is that **the progress is still not processed in main thread**.

[image: Still not on main thread]

Comment: Where is the [`RunWorkerAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync) method invoked?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, in CoreService.Init(), just line ahead of resolving it from DC.

Comment: Quoting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039587/how-to-make-backgroundworker-progresschanged-events-execute-in-sequence/8039614#8039614) answer: *`BackgroundWorker` raises `ProgressChanged` events on the current `SynchronizationContext` of the thread that called `RunWorkerAsync()`.*

Comment: As a side note, the `BackgroundWorker` class has been rendered [technologically obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker/64620920#64620920), after the advent of the async-await technology.

Comment: Usually a background worker should be created from the UI thread (of a WinForms application). This is generally done directly from the wizard. As it does not seems to be your case, then you might be using the wrong tool for the job (or at least you use it incorrectly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem after switching to `Task`s.

In that case, to report progress, I needed to use `Progress<T>`. This class is supposed to call the delegate in the thread it was constructed in, but in turn it just took a thread from the pool.

The reason was that initialization of my service (where `Progress<T>` was created) has been done in `App` ctor and it turs out, that **there is no `SynchronizationContext` there** (that is, `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null). In such case `Progress<T>` simply uses thread from pool and - most likely - `BackgroundWorker` does it too.

The Solution was to move initializaiton of my service to `Application_Startup`, where `SynchronizationContext` for main thread is already available.